# Cucumber ./features/step_definitions/calculator_steps.rb:15 in '/^the calculator is run$/

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd

I want to make it clear this problem is not about backticks.  I am new to Cucumber and am trying to run the code from second chapter of The Cucumber Book: Behavior-Driven Development for Testers and Developers.  I am using Cucumber 1.3.19 with ruby 1.9.3p551 in Windows 7 with Ansicon x64 1.60.  Cucumber works fine with other code I have received from others, so the configuration is good.  I have read several posts about problems with this tutorial in regards to the backticks already; however, I have copied the code directly from the Cucumber Book website with the correct backticks (not single quotes) and am still getting the error.

```
Command failed! <RuntimeError>
./features/step_definitions/calculator_steps.rb:15 in '/^the calculator is run$/
features\adding.features:5:in 'When the calculator is run'
Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features\adding.feature: 3
```

My code for adding.feature looks like

Feature: Adding

```
  Scenario: Add two numbers
    Given the input "2+2"
    When the calculator is run
    Then the output should be "4"
```

My code for the features/step_definitions/calculator_steps.rb looks like:

```
Given /^the input "([^"]*)"$/ do |input|
  @input = input
end

When /^the calculator is run$/ do
  @output = `ruby calc.rb #{@input}`
  raise('Command failed!') unless $?.success?
end

Then /^the output should be "([^"]*)"$/ do |expected_output|
  @output.should == expected_output
end
```

Is there something with the newer version of Cucumber that could render this code bad?

Comment: What output are you getting, and what were you expecting?

Comment: I get 1 failed scenario, 1 failed test, 1 skipped test, & the first test passes...The second test should pass according to the book....I think the third should as well, but the third will fail if the second fails.  I think the output is supposed to be testing the empty calc.rb file which is also in the same directory as the calculator_steps.rb file.  I know the book never mentions anything about that error.

Comment: Something is going wrong with one or both of the lines:

@output = `ruby calc.rb #{@input}`
  raise('Command failed!') unless $?.success?

Comment: could you show us the actual output? "something is going wrong" is not helpful.

Comment: Command failed! <RuntimeError>
./features/step_definitions/calculator_steps.rb:15 in '/^the calculator is run$/
features\adding.features:5:in 'When the calculator is run'
Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features\adding.feature: 3 #Scenario: Add two numbers  is the output 1 failed scenario, 1 failed, 1 skipped, & 1passed

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help.  I figured the problem out.  calc.rb needed to be in the root directory which was above features and I was putting it in the step_definitions :P.